# Get type of array values passed to function

Tags: typescript

I have function where i accept array of string literals, and then infer type of second argument based on given array. As the simplest example let's just make second argument be one of array values

```
type Foo = (arr: any[], bar: typeof arr[number]) => any
```

As you can probably guess bar type is actually any since it is any[] in type declaration even if i provide something like

```
fooFunc([const1, const2], somethingElse)
```

Typescript will allow it. I understand that you cannot make const arguments at least for now, but is there any workaround to make this work?

Simple changing arr type to string[] won't work

```
    const Codes = {
  "NOT_FOUND": "404",
  "FORBIDDEN": "403",
  "OK": "200"
   } as const

type Foo = (arr: string[], bar: typeof arr[number]) => any
const fooFunc: Foo = (arr, bar) => null;
fooFunc([Codes.FORBIDDEN, Codes.NOT_FOUND], "random string") //"random string" is string so it's completely ok
```

Changing arr type to Codes[] won't do the trick either, since it will allow Codes.OK which is not in our array.

Comment: "*i accept array of string literals*" then it's `string[]` not `any[]`. And the second argument will only be `string`, in that case. Is that what you want?

Comment: If i'll make it string[] it will accept any string not only literals that i've provided inside the array.

Comment: But the literals you have *are* strings. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've updated my question with piece of code which shows why this won't work. It will allow to use any string, not only string literals. And i'm trying to do function that infers type of second argument from literals in first argument. I'm using a little more complex logic in inferring type of the second argument, but the problem is the same. It doesn't get types from first array by using typeof arr[number]

Comment: So you want to make sure the second argument is in the array given?

Comment: I want to derive union type from array argument into second argument where i will use it to infer type of the second argument.

Comment: OK, let's clarify something a *string literal* is simply a string. It's a *literal* because in the code you don't generate it from anything, you simply have the string contents surrounded by `"` or `'` - that's it. So, `"hello"` is a *string literal* that has content `hello`. As opposed to, for example `String.fromCharCode(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)` which is *not* a literal but still a string.

Comment: To be honest i don't understand what you are trying to tell me. Yes, literal is a string, i've shown code which show why simply making type of array string[] doesn't help. Using typeof arr[number] gets strings instead of literal1 | literal2. So if i just set second argument to derived type as in my example it allows me to use ANY string while i want to only allow literals from array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good ol' typescript hacking will solve your issues.

```
const Codes = {
    "NOT_FOUND": "404",
    "FORBIDDEN": "403",
    "OK": "200"
} as const;
type Foo = <T extends typeof Codes[keyof typeof Codes], K extends T>(arr: T[], bar: K) => any;
const fooFunc: Foo = (arr, bar) => null;
fooFunc([Codes.NOT_FOUND, Codes.FORBIDDEN], Codes.NOT_FOUND); // allowed
fooFunc([Codes.NOT_FOUND, Codes.FORBIDDEN], Codes.FORBIDDEN); // allowed
fooFunc([Codes.NOT_FOUND, Codes.FORBIDDEN], Codes.OK); // errors
fooFunc(["123"], "123"); // errors
```

See it in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwiAJgUwjAvDA3gKBvmAIgDkB5AFQH0AxUgVWIBFCAuIgFgAZ3CAaPAoVoAlAEIBJRowCixVh04BmPgPyFSAaXmEATJ06EcAXxgBDNKEhQA3DigBPAA7IY1ECAwwAPORjIAHlDIYIhoDs4gAGbwSKgA2gDWyPZRMOHIqQgoEAC6vDAafoHBoTDkAHwAFKYATjVs5HF5MABGtWwaAJQY5WZg9raW0DCR7tQArmDAbG4emNV1+W013ei9YOMANpu2oyATU5VxWagAdGRUtAyM+ScQpyISUrLNd+cUNPRMndYwAPR-MzbEAAd2QiBwewOwCObwun2ut1i90ekhkxFeyIepDEaNkP3+gNMwLBEKhkxhxyx8KuTCR2WxuOeGPpZ00BIBfjqIBqEEhYwpR0IAEYdMpmiKxYQOYDkNzeTgcEA).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer could you please explain how does this strange generic interaction works or give link about it. I know how generics work and understand what generic that you've used does ( at least i think so ), but still don't get why this one works while the other one doesn't.

Comment: By default, typescript will choose the smallest possible union type for `T`, which would just be a union type consisting of all the elements of `arr`. Then, the generic requires that the type of `bar`, which is `K`, is a subset (essentially what `extends` means) of `T`, which essentially means that `bar` is in `arr.